# Issue with SQL updating php variable to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have the code below that UPDATE my database record.

```
$assign_id_input = $_POST['assign_id_input']; // Get ID input from user, it is always an integer

$assign_math = $_POST['input_math']; // Get the input from user

mysql_query("UPDATE free_ebook SET math = $assign_math WHERE useid = $assign_id_input;")or die(mysql_error());
```

I will display the SQL error below

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE useid = 8' at line 1

Comment: is it a typo `useid` `userid` ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the author didn't read the error message he posted which displays his problem in a clear manner.

Comment: Some people are new to PHP and SQL, so give them a break. If he couldn't get it then he came here to ask us. No point of him being stuck with this problem. When they fix it next time they run into the error they will know what to do.

Comment: **Holy Mother of SQL Injection**. Where's **Little Bobby Tables** these days?

Answer (score 0):

I bet your 'math' column is a String so you have to secure the String with quotes around your variable.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE free_ebook SET math = '$assign_math' WHERE useid = $assign_id_input;")or die(mysql_error()
```

Comment: I tried it display Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'math' at row 1.
It is a int(10) column

Comment: Ok that's the point, Your 'math' column is an int(10) but your variable '$assign_math' isn't. try printing this variable before the query in order to see what it contains.

Comment: $assign_math = $_POST['input_math'];

I key in integer in $_POST['input_math']

Answer (score 0):

Math data is in string format and it shoud be passed like a string

```
mysql_query("UPDATE free_ebook SET math = '$assign_math' WHERE useid = $assign_id_input;")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It display Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'math' at row 1.

Comment: `$assign_id_input = $_POST['assign_id_input']; // Get ID input from user, it is always an integer

$assign_math = $_POST['input_math']; // Get the input from user

mysql_query("UPDATE free_ebook SET math = '$assign_math' WHERE useid = $assign_id_input;")or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose variable names in SQLquery with single quotes like this:

Code:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE free_ebook SET math = '$assign_math' WHERE useid = '$assign_id_input'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `;` inside the query, take it out

```
mysql_query("UPDATE free_ebook SET math = '$assign_math' WHERE useid = $assign_id_input")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Still the same after I remove the ;

Comment: So it looks exactly like I have it? (I changed it a little)

Answer (score 0):

`'` is only use for column values, and it is for text/date/varchar types. Please take a look for column value which you are updating.

`mysql_query("UPDATE free_ebook SET math = '$assign_math' WHERE useid = $assign_id_input")`